# Worry vs worrying

Tags: gerunds

> 1. Perhaps the only thing growing faster than China's economy is **worry** about the country's economy.
> 2. Perhaps the only thing growing faster than China's economy is **worrying** about the country's economy.

Which one is correct? If both are correct, then what's the differences between them?

Answer (score 3):

Number one is correct, although I would suggest a change. Why is number one correct?

> Perhaps the only **thing** *growing* faster than China's economy is ***worry*** about the country's economy.

**Worry** agrees with **thing**. That is to say, 'worry' is a noun that we can consider a thing. *Worry* is also a thing that is capable of *growing*.

While gerunds *are* verb forms that function as nouns, we wouldn't think of **worrying** as a thing – we'd think of it as an **action**. Worrying isn't something that we would consider as capable of growing, either – although we could consider it capable of **becoming more commonplace**, for instance. (This wouldn't work if substituted into your sentence, however, as you can't say that China's economy is becoming more commonplace.)

As for my suggested change:

> Perhaps the only thing growing faster than China's economy is **concern** about **its** economy.
>
> Perhaps the only thing growing faster than China's economy is **anxiety** about **its** economy.

I would suggest using **concern** or **anxiety** for a couple of reasons.

The first is that 'worry' is not just a noun, but also a verb. This can create ambiguity in sentences, and can be a reason why a sentence might sound 'off' to native speakers. Concern or anxiety are both obvious nouns, so we don't have to spend any brainpower figuring out what form of 'worry' the writer is using.

The second is that 'growing concern' and 'growing anxiety' are both more commonplace phrases than 'growing worry'.

I have also suggested changing **the country's economy** to **its economy**, not because the former is incorrect, but because it is clear that **its** is referring to China, and the result is a more concise sentence.